# Как с помощью SQL выбрать только строки, имеющие определенное значение в одном из столбцов

Tags: php, mysql

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5,5
```

Данный запрос получает таблицу всех строк в обратном направлении...

Можно как то составить запрос чтобы выбирались не все строчки таблицы, а только определенные, которые к примеру будут иметь какое то свое значение в строчке в одном из столбцов.

Comment: Рекомендую изучать SQL не на форумах и Q&A, а по документации и книгам.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте директиву `where`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE row='value'
```

Запрос вернет все строки, где столбец с названием `row` равен значению `value`

Comment: Похоже то что надо!

Comment: И все же ошибку отдает... 
Я так прописал:
"SELECT * FROM knowledge_base ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5,5 WHERE forum='22'"

Comment: Разобрался, Работает отлично! Спасибо!

Comment: А не могли бы вы еще подсказать как узнать количество строк в таблице , где столбец с названием row равен значению value.

Comment: Сделал так SELECT COUNT(1) FROM knowledge_base WHERE forum='22' и что то оно мне не верно показывает...

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM knowledge_base WHERE forum='22'` - вернет 1 значение равное количеству строк у которых значение forum равно 22

Answer (score 0):

Используете конструкцию `WHERE`

Например, если хотите выбрать все строки, у которых `id` больше 5, используейте так

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id>5
```

Answer (score 0):

...WHERE `название столбца` = (равно, больше, меньше) 'значение';